# SignalR Passing a datatable back to ASP.NET webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I have just started getting into SignalR and I need to use it for a system dashboard.

Outside of this scope, there will be data going into a SQL Server database. I have written a stored procedure in SSMS which retrieves the state of the data from the external process.

I have created an ASP.NET web application which will call a server method which in turn will call the stored procedure to get the status of the data.

How can I pass a datatable (the results of the stored procedure) back to my client function and have JavaScript display it? The client page is .html, not webforms.

Right now I am just returning a string and an integer.

Current code

```
<p>Rows: <span id="rowselm"></span></p>
<p>Device: <span id="deviceelm"></span></p>

$(function () {
    var dashboard = $.connection.dashboard;
    dashboard.client.refreshDashboard = function (rows, device) {
        $('#rowselm').text(rows);
        $('#deviceelm').text(device);
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        dashboard.server.getDashboardData();
    });
})
```

Edit: here is my hub, demo just to show my approach.

```
public void GetDashboardData()
{
    dashboardItems = new List<DashboardItem>();

    int numberOfRecords = 144;
    string deviceId = "123-456-789";

    dashboardItems.Add(new DashboardItem { deviceID = deviceId, numberOfRows = numberOfRecords });

    Clients.All.refreshDashboard(dashboardItems);
}
```

So I can return a .NET type, but how do I handle that on the client?

Comment: You should consider passing an array of .NET objects back to the client (JS).  The objects will be serialized to JSON and you can render a table on the client-side.  You can directly pass the `DataTable` back to JS if you'd like but you will not like how it looks in JSON, I have tried it.

Comment: Also, can you share some of the code from you `Hub` -- are you getting an exception? what have you tried on the server-side?

Comment: Haven't tried, just didn't know how to handle a DT in JS. So you mean a list/array is the better way to go?

Comment: I mean that in a SignalR Hub you can pass any .NET object that is `Serializable` to the client and the objects will be serialized.  You don't really have to think about it.  If you pass a `DataTable`back to the client, the resultant JSON is sorta *ugly* -- using an `List<T>` or `Array` of a .NET object, the JSON will be in a more familiar format

Comment: Edited my question.